# Rails -- database index necessary for :id attribute?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-indexes

So as I was following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl I noticed that in the users table we added a unique index for the `:email` attribute to improve the efficiency of the `find` method so it doesn't search row by row.  So far we have been searching using both `find_by_email` and `find_by_id` depending on the case.  Yet we never set up an index for the  `:id` attribute.  Is `:id` automatically indexed because it is by default unique and sequential in nature?  Or is this not the case and should I add an index for `:id` searching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most databases (sqlite included, which is the default db in RoR) automatically index the primary key, which with Rails Migrations is `:id` by default.